# Fast flickering LED kitchen light fixture

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led

I have a LED kitchen light fixture which has been working great for around 18 months. There's no dimmer on it and it's controlled by a standard light switch. A couple of days ago it started flickering fast, so fast it was like a strobe light and hard to look at. So I ordered a new one which came today. When I wanted to make sure the power was off to the fixture when I replaced it the flickering was gone. What could the reason be? Is this an indication the fixture is bad, or just a freak incident that may not happen again? Nothing has changed in my kitchen and everything else electrical work as it should. I do not want to replace it if it's going to continue working. Maybe just keep the new one as backup in case the old one is on it's way out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ordered?  Can you link the product?

Comment: The old one I can't find a link for, but the new one I ordered is from Amazon: https://is.gd/PSBaVN

Answer (score 3):

It's the electronic driver, no doubt of it.

I couldn't quite read the numbers on it.  But it's calling out a very exact *current flow* (I underlined in red).... and a general/wide *working voltage* range (underlined in blue).

[image]

If you can find a driver module that same size, you can swap 'em out.  Current is the critical factor; it must be exact.  If you find drivers that aren't quite in that voltage range, you can carefully scrape the insulation off the 2 wires where I point to in green, and measure the lamp's actual working voltage with a voltmeter (while it's lit normally).  Your driver needs to support that voltage and 3-5 volts on either side.

My usual source for drivers is Mouser.com, and they have a search engine to let you narrow by current and voltage.  However a quick look showed a quality Meanwell unit, but it wasn't that shape (form factor).  Alibaba/AliExpress.com is *awash* with driver circuits of that exact form factor, in the $1 to $3 range, and ePacket delivery from China is cheap.  The downside of course is you're getting cheap Cheese junk, and it won't last any longer than the last one.

> Speaking of that... There are several Chinese dumpers who are absolutely flooding Amazon with junk.  The dumpers have certain patterns: Amazon *Marketplace* ("Sold by XXX and [Fulfilled by Amazon](https://services.amazon.com/fulfillment-by-amazon/benefits.htm)" right under the "Buy" button), no UL Listing nor any other reliable testing lab *(CE, ROHS, LVD and EMC are not a testing lab)*, the brand sounds weird and doesn't have a normal marketing/support/jobs website, the brand is fairly new, etc.
>
> Their typical business model is they find super cheap stuff on Alibaba/AliExpress, have the manufacturer  put them in boxes labeled for Amazon fulfillment, ship them straight from China to the Amazon warehouse, create a listing with price just a little below quality units, then sell a few units to shills who then write the [early fake reviews](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110824/shipped-package-arrived-didnt-order-possible-scam).  People get suckered in either because the product description is competent or they don't realize Amazon Marketplace is a flea market of junk.

At first I thought this was a dumper I call "Ikea Guy" (because he has hundreds of fake brands that sound like items in the Ikea catalog).  But now I'm not so sure, because I see non-Amazon sellers also selling them under that brand. They may just have a funny name and be fairly new.   Just be careful; products from those dumpers are the bottom of the barrel and simply will not last.  The 18 month experience is consistent with the dumped junk.

That's been my experience too.  I once bought a 10W LED security light for $10 from a dumper, and a $15 one from LEDWholesalers, who is an importer. Both Chinese of course but you could tell the latter was much better made.  The no-name one went out after a year. The other is still going after 6 years.

Comment: Thank you for a great and thorough comment. I learned a lot I did not know!  i finally found a link to this particular light. I notice that the driver has the same brand as the light itself "B & G": https://is.gd/ukurux. I added a better picture of the driver to the original post also. This morning it flickered again, but stopped after a few minutes. I think the easiest os putting up the light I got from Amazon. Worst case I get another year of service, but then I will come here and ask for a recommended light fixture! :)

Comment: I was right, that was a 54 and a 300... yes this item is definitely a cut above the cheap Cheese, *those guys* don't bother putting their consumer brand on the driver module.  I would contact S&G and see if they can help you out with a driver.

Comment: @Harper so the driver puts out a constant current (300 mA in this case) and varies the voltage to accomplish this? The driver is capable of voltage outputs in a certain range (here 54 to 85 V) depending on the load? Is a driver like this dimmable from its wall switch? So a single LED is designed to give rated light output at a certain current? Are the individual LEDs in a fixture like this in series or in parallel?

Comment: I added a picture of the markings on the new fixture. Is this one likely to last?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, LED devices operate in a constant-current (or rather, current-regulated) mode, for best performance without thermal runaway.   They are generally wired in series or a few series strings in parallel.  LEDs can be dimmed two ways, current reduction or extremely rapid flashing (far too fast to see) - this is incompatible with household triac dimmers, so dimmable LEDs have some smart electronics onboard to used the shaped power as a *signal* of dimming intent, and dim thusly.  Low voltage DC LEDs can dim much more elegantly.